# Two QTableViews in QLayout

Tags: qt, qtableview

I want to expand QTableViews' size so each QTableView takes the half size of the window! , how can i do it?

screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh87o.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Add a [QHBoxLayout](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qhboxlayout.html) to your widget/window and then add the tables to it.

The following code on a top level widget..

```
QHBoxLayout *horizontalLayout;
QTableView *tableView;
QTableView *tableView_2;

horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(Widget);
tableView = new QTableView(Widget);
horizontalLayout->addWidget(tableView);
tableView_2 = new QTableView(Widget);
horizontalLayout->addWidget(tableView_2);
```

Will give you something like..

[image]

The two tables share the available space equally and expand and resize with the main window.

Comment: that's what i have done, but i don't know how to expand the sizes of tables so each one takes half of the entire size's window.

Comment: I've added some code above. If you aren't getting that result, some other code or change is interfering with things.

Comment: yes i think that other code is interfering, but i don't know how to deal with it.